# PreSubmit event created for register action interrupt with login action in UserController

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following UserType.php file,

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Acme\UserBundle\Controller\UserController;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('UserName')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $User = $event->getData();

        $email = $User['email'];
        $UserObj = new UserController();
        $unique_id = $UserObj->idUnique($email);
        $User['userName'] = $unique_id;
        $event->setData($User);

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_userbundle_user';
    }
}
```

When user first registers in the site, I want to process his email to create unique id. For this, I get form data using events. Because, in symfony, you cannot modify form data after user pressing submit button. Hence, I use PreSubmit event to manipulate user's form data. It works well.

```
<?php
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   // here program control goes directly to preSubmit event created for registration.
}
```

Now, when the user log in to the system, I am using same **UserController.php** (specified in code above) and a method called "login". But, this time when the user presses submit button, he is taken directly to the onPreSubmit event created for the purpose of form data manipulation for registration. How should I change the login controller method so that **onPreSubmit** should not interrupt while program control goes to login method?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're using `UserType` for the login's form, right?

Comment: yes, this (**UserType**) is specifically used for building form for underlying objects of the class in Symfony2.

Comment: You should use different `Type`'s for login and registration. As a rule of thumb you want a `Type` for every form in your application.

Comment: @FyodorX Is that the correct way to do or some other option exists? because if I have to create more forms, I have to add Type for each one which seems quite tedious.  It would be nice if things are simple in Symfony2.

Comment: You have to define your form somehow. You could reuse your `Type` and hide fields on the view, but then validation becomes a crazy process and problems like this you're posting start popping up. So, having a `Type` for each form ***is*** the simple way.

Comment: @FyodorX Thanks. For login, how should I name Type.. like this UserLoginType? or LoginUserType?

Comment: Whatever you like. I would call it `LoginType`.